# Repeating alarm wont work in Android

Tags: android, notifications

User can set their own repeat interval, for example he/she selected 5 minutes to be reminded of the new goal she set. The reminder will start on the goal's start date which is also set by the user.

No problem with setting goal, and setting the repeat interval. The problem is it wont work.

**What i would like to happen:** This is an example

Goal 1 starts tomorrow. User will get reminder of Goal 1 in every 1 hour tomorrow.

Here's my code:

```
public void setReminder(){
        List<Goals> oneGoal = dbhandler.getLatestGoal(goal_id);

        for (final Goals goals : oneGoal) {

            if (repeat.isChecked()) {
                long futureInMillis = 0;
                dbhandler.updateReminders("true",choiceNumber,choiceRepeat,goal_id);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                cal.set(Calendar.DATE,Integer.parseInt(goals.getSDay()));  //1-31
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Integer.parseInt(goals.getSMonth())-1);  //first month is 0!!! January is zero!!!
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(goals.getSYear()));//year...

                //assigned a unique id to notifications
                Random random = new Random();
                int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

                //Create a new PendingIntent and add it to the AlarmManager
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
                intent3.putExtra("goalid", Integer.toString(goal_id));
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                        goals.getGoalId(), intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager am =
                        (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

                if (choiceRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Seconds")) {

                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000 * choiceNumber,
                        pendingIntent);
            } else if (choiceRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Minutes")) {
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000 * 60 * choiceNumber,
                        pendingIntent);

            } else if (choiceRepeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Hours")) {

                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * choiceNumber,
                        pendingIntent);
            }

                MessageTo.message(SetReminderActivity.this, "You will be reminded every "+choiceNumber+" "+choiceRepeat+" for the new goal.");

                //am.cancel(pendingIntent);
            }else{
                MessageTo.message(SetReminderActivity.this, "You've chosen not to set reminder for the new goal.");
            }
        }
    }
```

TimeAlarm.java // for the notifications

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

        NotificationManager nm;
        MyDBAdapter dbhandler;

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            int goal_id = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("goalid"));


            Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    new Intent(), 0);

            //assigned a unique id to notifications
            Random random = new Random();
            int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

            List<Goals> oneGoal = dbhandler.getLatestGoal(goal_id);

            for (final Goals goals : oneGoal) {

                Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("A Reminder from GSO")
                        .setContentText(goals.getGoalName())
                        .setSubText(goals.getStartDate() + " - " + goals.getEndDate())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gsoicon)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSound(soundUri)
                        .build();

                nm = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                // If you want to hide the notification after it was selected, do the code below
                mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                nm.notify(m, mNotification);


            }

        }
    }
```

in Android Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm" />
```

I can't tell what wrong with my code. Pls. help.

Comment: Add `com.yourPkgName.TimeAlarm` instead of only `.TimeAlarm`

Comment: i changed it but still wont work

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the alarm using AlarmManager's `set()` method. You should use `setRepeating()` method for repeating the alarm events.

So, your below line

```
am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

should be replaced with

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

You can also refer this [Example : Create Repeating Alarm](http://androidexample.com/Create_Repeating_Alarm_Start_After_Each_2_Minutes/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=93&aaid=116) .

Example to repeat event on every two minutes

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),2*60*60,pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="TimeAlarm" >
```

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html